# Google.Protobuf dose not allow null for properties

Tags: asp.net-core, protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-c

I am using GRPC on top of ASPNETCore, also have a model like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
message Blob {
    string id = 1;
    string path = 2;
}
```

The problem is that when i try to set the `path` property to null, It throws an `ArgumentException`.

simply running this code:

```
new Blob { Path = null };
```

Results into this:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')
   at Google.Protobuf.ProtoPreconditions.CheckNotNull[T](T value, String name)
   at Grpc.Blob.set_Path(String value)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Protobuf has no concept of null; with proto3 treating en empty string as "default, do not send", this means there is no payload difference between `null` and `""`. So: perhaps don't try and send `null`?

Alternatively: protobuf-net (which works fine with gRPC via protobuf-net.Grpc, which just attaches to the Google/Microsoft bits) would work fine here, and since it is not tied to proto3, it can be made to treat `null` and `""` differently (sending `""` explicitly as a zero length string and not sending `null` at all). You don't need a .proto for protobuf-net, but if you have one: https://protogen.marcgravell.com/

Comment: Oops silly me, That makes sense, thanks for explanation.